# Create dynamic table for offset and fetch next using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table name `mytable` which has row count 5300 (it should vary 2000, 3300 so on) and one IDENTITY columns: ID:

Case one: if `mytable` has 4500 rows and output should be like below.

| off | fetch |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 |
| 1001 | 2000 |
| 2001 | 3000 |
| 3001 | 4000 |
| 4001 | 4500 |

Case two: if `mytable` has 2450 rows and output should be like below.

| off | fetch |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 |
| 1001 | 2000 |
| 2001 | 2450 |

and so on. The difference between off and fetch is 1000.

Comment: i am thinking to create new column which 1- 1000 numbers only. then i will take min of  ID and Max of id.

Comment: what if there are gaps in your id's ?

Comment: no gaps in IDs. ID column is pk.

Comment: Anyone writing code should know about [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). What it does, how to use it. Works the same across many different environments.

Comment: Why would you need to dynamically set the _last chunk only_ to something less than 1000? If there are 2450 rows in the table you offset to 2001 and fetch next 1000 you're still only going to get 450 rows. Or is your intention really to fetch 1000 rows starting from 0 the first time, then 2000 rows starting starting from 1001, then 3000 rows starting from 2001, and so on? Why? If there are only 2450 rows in the table and you fetch 2450 rows starting at 2001, you're still only getting 450 rows.

Comment: Also, this doesn't address your question (which I just don't understand at all), but it is a fallacy to expect or assume that a column can't have gaps just because it's an identity column or it's the PK. Inserts can fail, rows can be deleted, whole ranges of values can be discarded when the service restarts or crashes, etc.

Comment: Do you want to run several SELECT's with `LIMIT 0,1000`, `LIMIT 1001,2000` etc?

Comment: i have got the solution with some changes in requirement. i will the update question with solution. thanks everyone for your guidance and support.

Comment: Please put the solution as an answer, not as part of the question. You are welcome to answer your own question

Comment: `no gaps in IDs. ID column is pk` why do you think there are no gaps because a column is a PK ?

Comment: yes, id column is pk. i haved used ntiles function which create equal group regardless gaps in ID column or not.. slight changes in original requirement but it meets the end goal for me. solution is posted. you can have a look. @Charlieface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:-

```
DECLARE @ROWSCOUNT decimal(10,0),
        @NTILES INT;
SET @ROWSCOUNT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [dbo].[tblLookupIncrementalLoad])
SET @NTILES = CEILING(@ROWSCOUNT/1000)

select a.concurrentPipelinecount, MIN(a.ID) AS offSetNum, max(a.ID) AS fetchNum, COUNT(concurrentPipelinecount) AS tableCount from 
(select *, NTILE (@NTILES) OVER (ORDER BY id) concurrentPipelinecount FROM [dbo].[tblLookupIncrementalLoad] where SkipFlag = 0) as a
GROUP by a.concurrentPipelinecount
```